# long Textview flickers when using linkify

Tags: android, textview, android-recyclerview, linkify, linkmovementmethod

I am using linkify to make links clickable in the textview. But whenever text length is big, the text flickers on scrolling or sometimes just disappears. The text view is part of header of recyclerview. Posting relevant code from activity class, its xml and adapter.

The Activity:

```
public class NewDiscussionDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_discussion_detail);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.detail_toolbar);
    aQuery = new AQuery(this);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    if (ab != null) {
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setTitle("Discussion");
    }

    Intent activityIntent = getIntent();
    discussion_id = Integer.parseInt(activityIntent.getStringExtra("discussion_id"));
    discussion_title = activityIntent.getStringExtra("discussion_title");
    discussion_text = activityIntent.getStringExtra("discussion_text");
    discussion_image_url = activityIntent.getStringExtra("discussion_image_url");
    comment_count = Integer.parseInt(activityIntent.getStringExtra("discussion_comment_no"));
    community_id = activityIntent.getStringExtra("community_id");
    community_name = activityIntent.getStringExtra("community_name");
    is_from_notification = activityIntent.getBooleanExtra("is_notification", false);

    // initializing header and footer for List view
    footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main_list_footer, null);
    header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.discussion_detail_header, null);

    prepareHeader(header);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.comment_list);
    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext());
    mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mLayoutManager.canScrollVertically();
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


    adapter = new CommentAdapter(commentList, this);

    /* download page 1*/
    adapter.addHeader(header);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    getCommentList();

    /* Scroll Listener which takes care of all triggers  to download to load data to adapter based position of the view*/
    // code for downloading more pages of comments
}

private void prepareHeader(View header) {
    /* preparing the header*/
    discussion_image = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.discussion_image_1);
    title = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.discussion_title);
    commentno = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.comment_count);
    description = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.discussion_text_content);

    title.setText(discussion_title);
    title.setTypeface(AppConstants.getTypeFaceBold(this));

    description.setText(discussion_text);
    discriptionText = discussion_text + "";
    Linkify.addLinks(description, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
    description.setTypeface(AppConstants.getTypeFaceNormal(this));

    if (comment_count > 2) {
        commentno.setText(String.valueOf(comment_count - 1) + " comments");
    } else if (comment_count == 2){
        commentno.setText(String.valueOf(comment_count - 1) + " comment");
    }else {
        commentno.setText("Be the first to comment");
    }


    if (discussion_image_url == null  || discussion_image_url.equals("")) {
        discussion_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        discussion_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        final String image_url = discussion_image_url;
        if(UtilMethod.isStringNullOrBlank(image_url))
        {
            //progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int width=dm.widthPixels;
        int height=dm.heightPixels;
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(image_url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.default_img_big).error(R.drawable.default_img_big)
                .transform(new ImageTransformation(width))
                .into(discussion_image, new Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
        discussion_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // code
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The Adapter:

```
public class CommentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
ArrayList<CommentListBean> mArrayList;
Context mContext;

String event = "";
public static final int TYPE_HEADER = 111;
public static final int TYPE_FOOTER = 222;
public static final int TYPE_ITEM = 333;
//headers
List<View> headers = new ArrayList<>();
//footers
List<View> footers = new ArrayList<>();

// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
public static class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    private View view;
    final TextView timestamp_tv;
    final TextView chat_username;
    final TextView description_tv;
    final ImageView author_image_view;
    final ImageView comment_image;

    public CustomViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        view = v;
        chat_username = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.comment_author_chatname);
        timestamp_tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.comment_timestamp);
        description_tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.comment_text);
        comment_image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.comment_image);
        author_image_view = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.comment_author_image);

    }
}

// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public CommentAdapter(ArrayList<CommentListBean> arrayList, Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mArrayList = arrayList;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
    if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.comment_list_item, null);

        CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    } else {
        //create a new framelayout, or inflate from a resource
        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(parent.getContext());
        //make sure it fills the space
        frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        return new HeaderFooterViewHolder(frameLayout);
    }
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)

public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    //check what type of view our position is
    if(position < headers.size()){
        View v = headers.get(position);
        //add our view to a header view and display it
        prepareHeaderFooter((HeaderFooterViewHolder) holder, v);
    }else if(position >= headers.size() + mArrayList.size()){
        View v = footers.get(position-mArrayList.size()-headers.size());
        //add oru view to a footer view and display it
        prepareHeaderFooter((HeaderFooterViewHolder) holder, v);
    }else {
        // - code for normal comment view
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    //check what type our position is, based on the assumption that the order is headers > items > footers
    if(position < headers.size()){
        return TYPE_HEADER;
    }else if(position >= headers.size() + mArrayList.size()){
        return TYPE_FOOTER;
    }
    return TYPE_ITEM;
}

private void prepareHeaderFooter(HeaderFooterViewHolder vh, View view){
    //empty out our FrameLayout and replace with our header/footer
    vh.base.removeAllViews();
    vh.base.addView(view);
}

//add a header to the adapter
public void addHeader(View header){
    if(!headers.contains(header)){
        headers.add(header);
        //animate
        notifyItemInserted(headers.size()-1);
    }
}

//remove a header from the adapter
public void removeHeader(View header){
    if(headers.contains(header)){
        //animate
        notifyItemRemoved(headers.indexOf(header));
        headers.remove(header);
    }
}

//add a footer to the adapter
public void addFooter(View footer){
    if (!footers.contains(footer)){
        footers.add(footer);
        //animate
        notifyItemInserted(headers.size()+mArrayList.size()+footers.size()-1);
    }
}

//remove a footer from the adapter
public void removeFooter(View footer){
    if(footers.contains(footer)) {
        //animate
        notifyItemRemoved(headers.size()+mArrayList.size()+footers.indexOf(footer));
        footers.remove(footer);
    }
}

//our header/footer RecyclerView.ViewHolder is just a FrameLayout
public static class HeaderFooterViewHolder extends CustomViewHolder{
    FrameLayout base;
    public HeaderFooterViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.base = (FrameLayout) itemView;
    }
}
```

}

XML for the header view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/message_list_image_layout"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="20dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="Representative image for the discussion"
                android:background="@color/background_color"
                android:id="@+id/discussion_image_1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_5"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
                android:src="@drawable/bg"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:maxHeight="280dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"  >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/discussion_title"
                android:text="This is heading of the content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_20"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_20"
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
                android:alpha="075" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/discussion_text_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_20"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_20"
                android:text="this is the text of content. this is the text of content. this is the text of content. this is the text of content. this is the text of content.this is the text of content. this is the text of content. this is the text of content. this is the text of content. this is the text of content."
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:alpha="0.75" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_20"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_20"
                android:background="@color/dark_background_color"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_10"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_20"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_20"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right|end"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/comment_count"
                    android:text="4 comments" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Screenshots

[Normal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIazx.jpg)

[when I scroll a bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UJJZ.jpg)

I have a feeling that it has something to do with LinkMovementMethod. Please help.